# updated node using brew upgrade node, but not updating

Tags: node.js, bash, homebrew

I have updated my node version using `brew upgrade node` and it shows this message:

```
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
Warning: node 18.4.0 already installed
```

but when I write `node -v` I get `v16.14.2`

Comment: What does `which node` show?

Comment: /Users/<USERNAME>/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node

Comment: I guess you have to choose if you want to keep using `nvm` to maintain Node.js versions, or Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using NVM also. Either do a

```
nvm install v18.4.0
nvm use v18.4.0
nvm alias default v18.4.0
```

or uninstall nvm and uninstall & install node via brew again.